# Добавление свойства элементу массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Почему можно программно(в цикле) добавить свойство элементу массива, при том что данный элемент строка,
например так:

```
arr.map((obj, i) => {
    obj.active = true
})
```

А руками написать такое свойство уже нельзя(или можно?)?

Comment: потому что любому объекту, если он не был заморожен можно добавить свойство. кроме того, если меняется сам элемент коллекции, а не нужно  получить новую - лучше использовать forEach вместо map

Comment: а руками как нибудь можно добавить свойство элементу массива, если элемент - строка?

Comment: _obj.active = true_, а может и нет :-) только если создавать _объект_ строки, через `new String`. С примитивами - не работает.